# Substituting lowerbacktitle in one-sided document

Tags: lyx, titles, front-matter, scrbook

I'm using LyX and the thesis template that comes with it. When I changed my document from two-sided to one-sided a page in the output disappeared. I found out that this was the `\lowertitleback` that requires a two-sided document (and that makes sense, I guess, since there is no back of the title on a one-sided document.)

Is there another command I can use that gives me the same result as `\lowertitleback` but on another page in a one-sides document?

**Edit:**
I'm thinking that `\maketitle` could be the way to go but that gives me a lot of problems:

- the first line of the page (listing names of my professors, referees
  etc.) is indented
- and empty heading line (as the one used in my chapters) is displayed
- the `\dedication` is shown on the same page as `\maketitle`. If I
  separate with `\clearpage` then the page with `\dedication` isn't
  displayed well - is has the heading line as well and it's no longer
  centered.

The easiest way to go would be to merge the pdf output of the `\lowertitleback` page from a two-sided version of the document with output of the one-sided one - but that would be cheating so I would like a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LyX thesis template is based on Koma-Script book ("scrbook.cls"). In this class `\maketitle` defines the sequence: title page, thanks, title back page, dedication. The title back page with `\uppertitleback` and `\lowertitleback` is only printed if in two-sided mode (you will find the condition `\if@twoside` in "scrbook.cls"). We remove this condition by setting it to "always true" just in this special location (i.e., we replace it by `\iftrue`). This is done by appending following lines to the LaTeX Preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\maketitle\endcsname{\if@twoside}{\iftrue}{}{}
```

Now the title back page is also printed in one-sided mode.

Comment: This suggestion does not work with current KOMA-Script nor with several outdated releases I've tested. Maybe it worked years ago, when the answer has been written. However, it always depended on undocumented class internals.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem outside the context of LyX. Markus Kohm (the author of KOMA-Script) suggested creating a `\forcetwosidetitle` command to solve this:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\newcommand*{\forcetwosidetitle}[1][1]{%
 \begingroup
   \cleardoubleoddpage
   \KOMAoptions{titlepage=true}% useful e.g. for scrartcl
   \csname @twosidetrue\endcsname
   \maketitle[{#1}]
 \endgroup
}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\uppertitleback{Test}
\title{Title}
\date{\today}
\forcetwosidetitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can switch to `twoside = semi` in one-page documents before `\maketitle` to force a double-sided title on titlepage = true, and subsequently switch back to a true one-page document with `twoside = false`.